# Creating Flutter AAR file using different lib/main_XXX.dart file

Tags: android, flutter, aar, flutter-module

Everyone. So I am trying to integrate Flutter module inside App(Android app).

So, I have followed [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup) tutorial and everything worked correctly.

To build an aar file the command is

```
 cd some/path/my_flutter
 flutter build aar
```

As per my project requirement, I thought of creating different configuration to `main.dart` file. Hence, I created `main_dev_dog.dart` and `main_dev_cat.dart` files.

The contents of this file is for **Cat**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'app_config.dart';

import 'my_app.dart';

void main() {
  const configApp = AppConfig(
      environment: Environment.DEV_CAT, appTitle: "Cat Dev", child: MyApp());

  runApp(configApp);
}
```

For **Dog**:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'app_config.dart';

import 'my_app.dart';

void main() {
  const configApp = AppConfig(
      environment: Environment.DEV_DOG, appTitle: "Dog Dev", child: MyApp());

  runApp(configApp);
}
```

PS: I am not trying to create **Flavors**.

**My intentions is to create aar files which will have different configuration. And I can use those libraries(aar) in Android Native app.**

I am not sure if it is possible? But I know we can build different APK's using different `main.dart` files.

For example:

```
flutter build apk -t lib/main_dev_dog.dart
```

or

```
flutter build apk -t lib/main_dev_cat.dart
```

So, I tried following command to create different AAR:

```
flutter build aar lib/main_dev_cat.dart
```

But it is not building and I am getting following error.

```
Could not transfer artifact com.akshay.first.my_flutter_module:flutter_debug:aar:1.0 from/to remote (file://./build/host/outputs/repo): Repository path /build/host/outputs/repo does not exist, and cannot be created.
Could not transfer artifact com.akshay.first.my_flutter_module:flutter_debug:pom:1.0 from/to remote (file://./build/host/outputs/repo): Specified destination directory cannot be created: /build/host/outputs/repo/com/akshay/first/my_flutter_module/flutter_debug/1.0

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter:uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.akshay.first.my_flutter_module:flutter_debug:aar:1.0 from/to remote (file://./build/host/outputs/repo): Repository path /build/host/outputs/repo does not exist, and cannot be created.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you using any dependency for project from any repo?

Comment: I did not get your question. For Flutter Module no there are no dependencies yet.(It is just POC but it will). And for native project. Yes, standard android dependencies like Retrofit, Coroutines. And Flutter module repo.